# How to create a simple list using in this example?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I do a fetch(url), the body of the response looks like this:

```
{
    "test1": {
        "url": "https://nexus.test.com/1.zip"
    },
    "test2": {
        "url": "https://nexus.test.com/2.zip"
    },
    "test3": {
        "url": "https://nexus.test.com/3.zip"
    },
    "test4": {
        "url": "https://nexus.test.com/4.zip"
    },
}
```

I am trying to just add test1, test2, test3 to a list.  I'm not actually sure how to do this in javascript.  I tried using a for loop, but that failed miserably.

**solution that is failing**:

```
    myList = []
    for(i in testjson[i]) {
        console.log(i)
        myList.push(i)
    }
```

How can I add these elements to the list (ignoring url)

Answer (score 0):

If you want exclusively just `test1`, `test2` and `test3` this code will work:

```
  myList = []
  for (var key in testjson) {
             if(key === "test1" || key === "test2" || key === "test3") {
                 myList.push(testjson[key]); 
             }
  }
```

If you want to exclude `test4`

```
  myList = []
  for (var key in testjson) {
             if(key !== "test4") {
                 myList.push(testjson[key]); 
             }
  }
```

Consider reading more about [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: need solution where name of hte keys are not known

Comment: so what are you trying to do, take first 3 or exclude last 1. can you be more specific?